# How to automatically update the child view when the parent view's frame changes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard, ios-app-extension

I am revising a custom keyboard application. My first attempt using Stack views to layout views had a performance hit of 4-6 seconds of delay. So, I am making a new custom keyboard using Custom View and calling `layoutSubviews()` to well, layout its views.

Now, I have made a custom view that represents the keyboard. By the way, I am hardcoding the values for the keyboard size. So, this one will work for iPhone 5 and 5s only. ( I'm checking the view's frame width for this.)

Now, I want to make the keyboard's view controller to update the custom view's frame whenever the view controller bounds update!

> How to set the custom view to the parent to fill the parent width and height such that it updates the custom view's bounds/frames whenever the view controller's bound change?

Here's the code so far.

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    var keyboardView: KeyboardView?


    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       view.autoresizesSubviews = true

        keyboardView = KeyboardView(frame: view.frame)

        view.addSubview(keyboardView!)

    }




}
```

And, here's the code for the custom view.

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardView: UIView {

    // MARK:- Properties
    var row1ButtonLabels = ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P"]

    var row1Buttons = [UIButton]()
    var row2Buttons = [UIButton]()
    var row3Buttons = [UIButton]()
    var row4Buttons = [UIButton]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        for i in 0..<10 {

            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 12, width: 26, height: 38))
            button.setTitle(row1ButtonLabels[i], forState: .Normal)

            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("printCharacter"), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)



            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.45)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0

            row1Buttons.append(button)


            addSubview(button)
        }


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        for i in 0..<10 {



            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 12, width: 26, height: 38))
            button.setTitle(row1ButtonLabels[i], forState: .Normal)

            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("printCharacter"), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)



            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.45)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0

            row1Buttons.append(button)


            addSubview(button)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        print("LayoutSubviews")

        if frame.width == 320 {


            var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 12, width: 26, height: 38)

            for (index, button) in row1Buttons.enumerate() {

                // If button is first button, then add leadingSpace
                // Else it is ( leadingSpace + (buttonWidth + interButtonSpace) * index )
                let xPosition = index == 0 ? 3 : (3 + 26 * index + 6 * index)

                buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(xPosition)

                button.frame = buttonFrame

            }

        } else if frame.width == 568 {

            var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: 47, height: 32)

            for (index, button) in row1Buttons.enumerate() {

                // If button is first button, then add leadingSpace
                // Else it is ( leadingSpace + (buttonWidth + interButtonSpace) * index )
                let xPosition = index == 0 ? 26 : (26 + 47 * index + 5 * index)


                buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(xPosition)

                print("Frame: \(buttonFrame)")

                button.frame = buttonFrame

            }

        }
    }

    // Ignore this for now, only for testing if keyboard is working or not. And, it worked.
    func printCharacter(){        


        for button in row1Buttons {

               button.setTitle( button.titleLabel?.text?.lowercaseString , forState: .Normal)

        }
    }

}
```

**Note:** I implemented the init(coder) only for testing it in the storyboard. So, please ignore it as well.

Also, my custom keyboard is now working fine and is running on with 2-3 seconds delay only on iPhone 6s. But, that's to be expected for having a background image also.

Moving back to question, I know layoutSubviews will be called whenever the custom view's frame changes. I want the custom view to take the full frame size of the keyboard view controller as the keyboard should take the full frame size, it is to be expected.

Requested:

> How to set the custom view to the parent to fill the parent width and height such that it updates the custom view's bounds/frames whenever the view controller's bound change?

I am not using auto layout for this, though it is enabled fairly. So, it is only done programatically.

I am also tracking onto it and am studying the documentation for UIView. I have come in touch with two properties: `autoresizingMask` and `autoresizesSubviews`, and am currently checking if they could help me on this. I am choosing to layout subviews by myself because the performance hit is really high in case of auto layouts. But that's just my personal preference.

Again, for you who is interested in helping me, I am hardcoding for each device. I am currently hardcoding for 320x568 i.e. iPhone 5 and 5s. The custom dimension in use for keyboard is 320x216pt and 568x162pt.

---

**Update:** Every time the controller updates its bounds, I implicitly want to set the frame of the custom view to the parent's bound. Could this be done from `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` and/or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. I want to set to the following frame size. I did get the size in those method.

Is it appropriate to update the subviews from `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` and / or `viewDidLayoutSubviews?`

> CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: parent_width, height: parent_height)